# GTM data layer eventCallback function

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

So i have Ecommerce code setup in GTM data layer, but after that is sent to Analytics i want the page to be redirected so i know i should be using eventCallback but it is not working for some reason.

```
<body>
<script>
    dataLayer = [{
        'transactionId': '56833',
        'transactionAffiliation': 'TestName',
        'transactionTotal': 1540.00,
        'transactionTax': 385,
        'transactionShipping': 0,
        'transactionProducts': [{
            'sku': 'FFSS44HH',
            'name': 'test',
            'category': 'TestCategory',
            'price': 1540.00,
            'quantity': 2
        }],
        'eventCallback': function() {
            document.location.href='https://www.paypal.com/something';
        }
    }];
</script>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

I have set up Ecommerce firing rule in GTM for this URL. I tried hitCallback and eventCallback but the redirect does not happen... What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Would you need to do a datalayer.push in order to trigger the eventCallback, as per this resource: http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/hitcallback-eventcallback/?

Comment: There is something really wrong, becouse i tryed copy pasting some examples and they still dont work. I tried dosument.location and alert so i just see a message, but nothing works... Do you have any idea what could i be doing wrong here?

Comment: You don't have an `event` parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think i found a solution, i just added this ('event' : 'datalayerReady') at the end of the data layer:

```
'event' : 'datalayerReady',
'eventCallback': function() {
  document.location = "https://www.paypal.com/something";
}
```

Comment: this is correct, because every push into dataLayer has to have defined 'event' otherwise it ll not be processed/fired

Answer (score 12):

Taken from: 
http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/use-eventtimeout-eventcallback/

Always add the `eventTimeout` parameter when using `eventCallback`. The former takes a numerical value as its parameter, representing the number of milliseconds to wait before calling `eventCallback` anyway. In other words, even if your Tags stall and never signal completion, after two seconds `eventCallback` is invoked.

```
window.dataLayer.push({
  'event' : 'processLink',
  'eventCallback' : function() {
    window.location = targetUrl
  },
  'eventTimeout' : 2000
});
```

Comment: essential part should be here

Comment: Is there any official Google hosted documentation on these parameters?

Answer (score 3):

This works well for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof dataLayer !== "undefined") {
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'MyEvent',
            'eventCallback' : function() {
                window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802554/gtm-data-layer-eventcallback-function';
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802554/gtm-data-layer-eventcallback-function" />
</noscript>
```

Comment: GTMtips: hitCallback And eventCallback

http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/hitcallback-eventcallback/

Comment: It seems the only solution in this thread

Answer (score -2):

Dreadlord,

try using this: (no *href* after *window.location*)

```
'eventCallback': function() {
    window.location.href = 'https://www.paypal.com/something';
}
```

This should fix it. Hope this helps,
Petr

Comment: document.location and document.location.href should work the same, should they not?

Comment: i tryed with and without href but it is still not redirecting anywhere... Do you know what else could i try?

Comment: It should be window.location.href, not document.location.href

Comment: thank you @rolznz for the correction, updated my answer accordingly