# Google Tag Manager Events showing up on Google Analytics inconsistently

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In this project I'm in, they have configured GTM and GA to work together to track particular events. I was asked to find the root cause of some kind of a leak that's happening.

Currently, the events are being tracked with the eventLayer.push strategy. Those events are handled by the Event Tag in GTM, which sends them to GA.

When testing them, it's happening that the events aren't reaching GA 100% of the time. Even the same event, doesn't hit GA every single time it's being triggered. I'm looking into

This is leading to issues when analyzing the results GA gives.

To test this, I've been trying the Preview Mode on GTM. When doing so, I can see that every event that is triggered appears there. However, not all of them appear in the real-time view of GA. Here's an example of this:

https://b.imge.to/2019/07/16/LVqot.png

Then, I started using the Tag Assistant Chrome's extension to find out if it was helpful, and I got to see some errors there. This is an example:

https://b.imge.to/2019/07/16/LV18x.png

To make this, the events are being pushed like this:

```
dataLayer.push({'eventCategory': 'sign in', 'eventAction': 'click', 'eventLabel': 'sign-in-popup', 'event': 'click-sign-in-popup'});
```

and GTM is being embedded like this:

```rb
:javascript
  dataLayer = []
/ Google Tag Manager
:javascript
  (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
  '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','#{ENV['GTM_CONTAINER_ID']}');
/ End Google Tag Manager
```

To clarify, the GTM container is already published. I can't find the reason of why sometimes events reach GA

Comment: Couple of things to check. Make sure that any ad-blocking extensions you have installed are disabled or whitelisted for your site. Second, make sure that if that event is fired when the user is being redirected (maybe clicking a link that takes them somewhere else), you only redirect them ***after*** the event has completed, by using an [event callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38976722/11447682). The net::ERR_ABORTED usually means the network request did not complete, and those are two likely culprits.

Comment: @JoshuaT Thanks for your comment! I didn't know about that event callback. I'll give it a try and tell you, but it really sounds that it could help.