# capture data sent to google-analytics using cypress

Tags: google-analytics, automated-tests, cypress, end-to-end

I am trying to use cypress for testing.
whenever anybody clicks any link in my website, it sends data to google-analytics.
now i should test where data is sent or not to google-analytics using cypress.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Do you want to test that google analytics is called? You could stub the request perhaps and assert on the request sent.

Comment: @Maccurt , yes i want to test that google analytics is called or not, thank you for your response, could you if possible show me how to use stub to track the request?

Comment: I won't put an answer because I don't know the exact code. First this seems like it could be written with a unit test easier, but since you are doing cypress I will tell you my thoughts and if I can code it up, I will put an answer. First you are able to MOCK/STUB an API call so you could do that to your API call to google, and then you have assert on a REQUEST that it got called (or not), let me see if I can find the code for it..

Comment: okay,, thanks @Maccurt

Answer (score 1):

Simply blacklist *google-analytics.com by adding an entry to cypress.json like this:

```
{
  "blockHosts": [
    "*google-analytics.com",
    "*googletagmanager.com"
  ],
  "video": false
}
```

[cypress’ documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#blockHosts)

Comment: Not really the right answer for this question - he wanted to capture the GA data.

Answer (score 0):

Available options:

- **GA's [`hitCallBack`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#hitCallback) method** notifying you something was tracked
- **GA's [custom tasks](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks)** allowing you to extend GA default execution flow ([see example hooking into `sendHitTask`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks#adding_to_a_task) to dispatch data to localhost in addition to GA) to not only know when something was tracked, but also `retrieve a copy of the entire payload sent to GA`.
- **GTM's [`eventCallback`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802554/gtm-data-layer-eventcallback-function) method** should you decide to track GA via Google Tag Manager

Any of the above methods can be used to update a variable cypress can evaluate to determine whether things were tracked properly.

**Please note that GA tracking is ASYNC** so you'll [need to adapt your cypress code accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980311/cypress-io-how-to-handle-async-code).

Comment: can you provide a link/example, i am new to testing as well as development, and didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `cy.stub`, here is an [example](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/stubbing-spying__google-analytics).